# How to check if a folder exists automatically without ".click" function

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem.  I have a program written in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2013 and it works good.  The problem is that I want the program to check if a folder exists on program start-up and return a text value in a label without having to manually "click" the label.  I have searched and cannot find anything, maybe I'm not searching for the right thing?

Here is a sample of the check:

```
''//ASDG_JR check
Private Sub lbl_asdg_jr_pres_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbl_asdg_jr_pres.Click
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(user_txt_dir.Text & "\@ASDG_JR_v0.14") Then
        lbl_asdg_jr_pres.Text = "All good!"
        btn_asdg_di.Text = ".zip file downloaded already"
        btn_asdg_unzip.Text = "unzipped and installed already"
        btn_asdg_di.Enabled = False
        btn_asdg_unzip.Enabled = False
    Else
        lbl_asdg_jr_pres.Text = "Use buttons ----->"
        btn_asdg_di.Enabled = True
        btn_asdg_unzip.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If your app starts from Sub Main - place the code there.  If it is form driven put it in Form Load.  It is not uncommon to have a set of things to do the first time an app is run on a given machine.

Comment: Thank you sir for responding, I will check into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code inside the form's load event.

```
Private Sub myForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles myForm.Load
    'If directoryExists Then update label
End Sub
```